# Most efficient way of generating random ERC 721 NFT

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, erc-721

I'm just getting into Solidity by building a first project around collectibles, ERC 721.

There's for example 1500 different collectibles, each has an available amount defined by a criteria. These collectibles will be distributed in packs of 5, totally randomly after an initial purchase. These collectibles will be generated from a database that has properties like "name", "image", "id", etc

How would one go about generating 1500 * availability tokens (amounting to a total of 150000 tokens)? Pass an array of ids to a function called only once from a specific private address and generate them and store them in a mapping storage? I'm anticipating this will require a lot of gas, how could I evaluate the costs of creating such a large number of tokens?

Comment: Will you do all 150,000 in one series? Or will you have multiple series? It makes a difference in the type of solution that will be appropriate.

Comment: I have the same doubt, did you resolve it??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `ERC721` has its amount fixed as 1, so you might wanna use `ERC1155`.

If you want to create **1500K** `ERC721` or 1500 `ERC1155`(**1K** of each) collectibles, I would not suggest you create all of them in one go, as there is a high possibility that they will exceed the `block gas limit`.

From your question, I see that you have all the different `token URIs` stored in a `database`. So, you can create these collectibles in *batches*, such that it's efficient for you.

You can use `truffle` or `hardhat` for gas estimation.